# Regex: Trying to extract all values (separated by new lines) within an XML tag

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a project that demands extracting data from XML files (values inside the `<Number>`... `</Number>` tag), however, in my regular expression, I haven't been able to extract lines that had multiple data separated by a newline, see the below example:

[image: obnoxious image of text]

As you can see above, I couldn't replicate the multiple lines detection by my regular expression.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Notepad++ isn't a programming language so it doesn't really "extract" anything. It can transform your data into something more usable. What's your end goal with the data; what should it look like? It could take multiple Notepad++ operations to achieve your goal.

Comment: Well, I want to "Mark" the needed data so I can copy it and use it on my project, I have multiple XML files with this format, and there are multiple tags within the files that have multiple entries, I need a reg expression that can cover all the data in between the <Number> </Number> tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i was able to find the right regular expression, I'll leave it below if anyone needs it:

`<Type>\d</Type>\n<Number>(\d+\n)+(\d+</Number>)`

Explanation:

- `\d`: Shortcut for digits, same as [1-9]
- `\n`: Newline.
- `+`: Find the previous element 1 to many times.

Have a good day everybody,

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a script somewhere, your first plan should be to use a XML parser. Almost every language has one and it should be far more accurate compared to using regex. However, if you just want to use regex to search for strings inside npp, then you can use `\s+` to capture multiple new lines:

```
<Number>(\d+\s)+<\/Number>
```

https://regex101.com/r/MwvBxz/1

I'm not sure I fully understand what you are trying to do so if this doesn't do it then let me know what you are going for.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your help, unfortunatley it didn't work, to put it simply lets say we have the follwoing XML data: <Type>3</Type>
     <Number>3629
3361
3362
33601
33602
33603
33604
33605
33606
33609
33610
33611
33634
33635
33636
33641 </Number> 
I want to get the number values only inside the tag, thanks again for trying to help

Answer (score 0):

You can use this find+replace combo to remove everything which is not a digit in between the `<Number>` tag:

Find:

```
.*?<Number>(.*?)<\/Number>.*
```

Replace:

```
$1
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well, I want to "Mark" the needed data so I can copy it and use it on my project, I have multiple XML files with this format, and there are multiple tags within the files that have multiple entries, I need a reg expression that can cover all the data in between the <Number> </Number> tags

Answer (score 0):

After giving it some more thought I decided to write a second answer.

You can make use of look arounds:

```
(?<=<Number>)[\d\s]+(?=<\/Number>)
```

https://regex101.com/r/FiaTKD/1